# How to change a PG column to NULLABLE TRUE?

Tags: sql, postgresql, nullable

How can I accomplish this using Postgres? I've tried the code below but it doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn BIGINT NULL;
```

Answer (score 895, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP NOT NULL;
```

There's no need to specify the type when you're just changing the nullability.

Comment: The inverse is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197236/change-column-type-and-set-not-null

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek mind-reader ?

Comment: Looks like the pg manual page moved here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html

Comment: @Kramer Thanks for the heads up on the link change.