# ALTER TABLE, set null in not null column, PostgreSQL 9.1

Tags: postgresql, null, postgresql-9.1

I have a table with not null column, How to set a null value in this column as default?

I mean, I want to do something like this:

```
postgres=# ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone SET NULL;
```

but it shows:

```
postgres=# ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone SET NULL;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NULL"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone SET NULL;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a PG column to NULLABLE TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812933/how-to-change-a-pg-column-to-nullable-true)

Comment: The request to "set null in a not null column" means to remove the "NOT NULL" CONSTRAINT on that column: "ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone DROP NOT NULL;"

Answer (score 344, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone DROP NOT NULL;
```

More details in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 81):

Execute the command in this format

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname SET NOT NULL;
```

for setting the column to not null.

Comment: Column names must not be enclosed in single quotes

Comment: This helped me, even though it didn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer the question! I cannot understand why it has that many upvotes.

Answer (score 26):

Execute the command in this format:
`ALTER [ COLUMN ] column { SET | DROP } NOT NULL`

Answer (score 23):

```
First, Set :
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone DROP NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Came here searching for how to set the column as NOT NULL. With your answer, I could figure the solution: `ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN phone SET NOT NULL`. Thanks!