# How to set not null constraint to columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, alter-table

I tried to set null to columns like following.

`ALTER TABLE myschema.table ALTER COLUMN (test_id,type) SET NOT NULL;`

But it returned syntax error like  `Syntax error at or near Line 3, Position 47`

Are there any proper way to achieve this ?

If someone has opinion please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change column type and set not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197236/change-column-type-and-set-not-null)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't provide a list of column in parentheses, you need to use multiple ALTER COLUMN options separated by a comma:

```
ALTER TABLE the_table
    ALTER COLUMN test_id set not null, 
    ALTER COLUMN type SET NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try doing it separately for both the columns:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.table ALTER COLUMN test_id SET NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE myschema.table ALTER COLUMN type SET NOT NULL;
```