# DROP NOT NULL CONSTRAINT

Tags: postgresql, hsqldb

How to drop not null constraint that will work both in PostgreSql and HSQL?

I'm using: `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname DROP NOT NULL;` 
But it's not working in HSQL.

This column was created: `columnname TEXT NOT NULL,`

Comment: See the manual: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#N11364

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change a PG column to NULLABLE TRUE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812933/how-to-change-a-pg-column-to-nullable-true)

Answer (score 5):

The current HSQLDB syntax is: `ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname SET NULL` But the PostgreSQL syntax will be supported in HSQLDB version 2.3.4 release.