# Flyway and PostgreSQL nullable definition of foreign key still generates a non-null constraint

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, flyway

I use Spring Boot and Flyway with this initialization script:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS(
    ID bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
                    );

CREATE TABLE ROLE(
    ID bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    ID bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
    ADDRESS bigserial NOT NULL REFERENCES ADDRESS (ID),
    ROLE bigserial REFERENCES ROLE (ID)                  -- notice here is no 'not null'
);
```

All the relationship between the tables is that:

- Each `PERSON` has `0-1` `ROLE`. So, each  `ROLE` belongs to `0-n` `PERSON`. Hence, this relationship is nullable.
- Each `PERSON` has `1` `ADDRESS`. So, each `ADDRESS` belongs to `1-n` `PERSON`. Hence, this relationship is not-null.

As soon as I start the application (I have also tried to post the query straight to the PostgreSQL database schema), there is somehow generated constraint `not-null` between the `PERSON` and `ROLE` tables.

Using DataGrip, I select <kbd>SQL Scripts</kbd> -> <kbd>Generate DDL to Query Console</kbd> and get the DDL for the tables (see below, new lines and roles definitions omitted for sake of brevity).

To my surprise, the `NOT NULL` is there although I haven't defined such constraint. How to get rid of it aside from altering table?

```
create table if not exists address
(
    id bigserial not null
        constraint address_pkey primary key
);

create table if not exists role
(
    id bigserial not nullconstraint role_pkey primary key
);

create table if not exists person
(
    id bigserial not null 
        constraint person_pkey primary key,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    address bigserial not null 
        constraint person_address_fkey references address,
    role bigserial not null                                   -- why is 'not null' here?
        constraint person_role_fkey references role
);
```

---

The version of PostgreSQL I use (through `SELECT version()`) is:

```
PostgreSQL 10.13, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
```

Comment: Note that with Postgres 10 or later `identity` columns are recommended over `serial` anyway: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["8.1.4. Serial Types"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types `smallserial`, `serial` and `bigserial` are not true
> types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique
> identifier columns (similar to the `AUTO_INCREMENT` property supported
> by some other databases). In the current implementation, specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname SERIAL
> );
> ```
>
> is equivalent to specifying:
>
> ```
> CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq AS integer;
> CREATE TABLE tablename (
>     colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
> );
> ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
> ```

Note the `NOT NULL`.

Don't use `bigserial` for the **foreign** key. That doesn't make much sense. Simply use `bigint`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
                           (...
                            role bigint REFERENCES role);
```

Comment: This is even more more obvious when using the (recommended) `identity` instead of `serial`

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `bigserial` is good for the primary key definition as long as it specifies the autoincrement and `bigint` is appropriate for referencing such keys?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis: `bigint` is the underlying actual data type here. Using `bigserial` is also a `bigint`, it just adds some voodoo to automatically create unique values for the column using a sequence, like some macro that expands if you will. For primary keys that's convenient. But automatically creating values for a foreign key doesn't make much sense. They'd just more or less randomly reference a record (at least likely not the one you want) or occasionally generate a value not existing in the referenced table inducing an error. That's not so convenient.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution 1:
Changing `Biserial` to `Bigint` does not remove the null constraint set to foreign key column when running flyway in springboot to write into postgres DB (at least for my case)

- postgres:11.3-alphine 3.4
- flyway: 8.0.5

To be secure, need to add scripts to alter columns to be nullable

`ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mycolumn DROP NOT NULL;`

[Change Postgres column to nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812933/how-to-change-a-pg-column-to-nullable-true/4813062)

Possible solition 2:
When Spring boot set JPA Hibernate ddl configuration to `create`, `create-drop`, `update`, flyway DB migration script will be updated by JPA entities properties. NOT NULL constraints can be added by JPA entities.

Change JPA Hibernate ddl configuration to `none` or `validate` will ensure only flyway script is used to create schema.
[JPA Hibernate ddl configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135114/how-does-spring-jpa-hibernate-ddl-auto-property-exactly-work-in-spring)